# How to checkout from repository and assign working sets in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I am working with Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. I am performing SVN checkout of java projects from a repository and I want to add these projects to working sets while performing the checkout. I see no option in the SVN checkout window to do this. So I have to sit and move the projects from 'Other Projects' to the required working sets. Is there a way to do this automatically while doing the checkout (and save time)?

Comment: you mean `svn checkout` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
File  > Import ... > SVN > Import project from SVN >
```

and then follow the steps

once you are done with checkout successfully

you can select project in project explorer view and then

```
right click  > assign working sets...
```

Comment: I know how to perform an SVN checkout. I want the projects to go into specific working sets after checkout. How do I specify which working sets the projects should be assigned to? This is my question.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you are saying. The question is, is there a way to assign working sets while starting the checkout, so that I don't have to manually perform the working set assignment? This will save a lot of time for me as I have to checkout from multiple locations into multiple working sets and I can run the checkouts parallelly without having to monitor the progress continuously.

Comment: Jigar, your response just reiterates the process that I have been following (your answer is just a more step-by-step process of what I have already said in the question), which is a little tedious for me, and requires monitoring. Do you think there is a way for things to get simpler?